# How to blur View with Animation in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, blur

I am blurring a View depending on the `Scene Phase`. I also added `withAnimation { ... }`, however, the `Blur-Transition` happens without any Animation. Check out my Code:

```swift
@main struct ExampleApp: App {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    @State private var blurRadius: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            RootView()
                .blur(radius: blurRadius)
                .onChange(of: scenePhase, perform: { value in
                    switch value {
                        case .active : withAnimation { blurRadius = 0 }
                        case .inactive: withAnimation { blurRadius = 15 }
                        @unknown default: print("Unknown")                    
                    }
                })
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an Idea why the `Blur-Status` changes without any `Animation`?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not reproducible for me on iOS 14.4 simulator -- the blur animation appears to work fine.

Comment: @jnpdx The Blur is working, however I would like it to appear / disappear with a Animation of a duration of about 0.5 seconds. This Animation does not work for me.

Comment: I spoke too soon -- looks like if I do this all inside of a `View`, it works fine (eg inside `RootView`), but at the top level inside `WindowGroup`, I'm seeing the same thing you are -- no animation. But, that may be a hacky solution for you -- move this behavior inside your root view.

Comment: @jnpdx Could the Problem be, that the Animation gets initiated the moment the App's Scene Phase changes to `Inactive` and maybe Animations does not work when the App is `inactive`?

Comment: I don't think so, because the scene changes/animations work fine when inside the `RootView`. It might just be that the `App` responds differently to the environment change and animation than a `View` does.

Comment: @jnpdx Thanks for your help. I moved the `Blur` inside the `RootView` and it's now working like expected. Feel free to publish your solution so I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this behavior doesn't seem to work correctly as the root node inside an `App`, it *does* seem to work if you move the blur and animation *inside* the `View`:

```
struct RootView: View {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    @State var blurRadius : CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .blur(radius: blurRadius)
            .onChange(of: scenePhase, perform: { value in
                switch value {
                case .active : withAnimation { blurRadius = 0 }
                case .inactive: withAnimation { blurRadius = 15 }
                @unknown default: print("Unknown")
                }
            })
    }
}
```